# How can I change the order of my recyclerView items by changing values in the database?

Tags: java, kotlin, arraylist, android-recyclerview, android-sqlite

In my app, the user should be able to change the order of the item. I am having the data from the table by SELECT statement order by Order field, and storing the result in the List. Then I am showing the List data in the Recycler View.

I would like to move "Item 5 " from recycler view position 4, and Order field value 12 to recycler view position 1.

**My first question** :
How do I move the Item 5 to recycler position 1 using Java/Kotlin?

**My second question**:
How do I move the Item 5 to recycler position 1 and change the Order field in DB accordingly? Means when I move the Item 5 to recycler position 1 the Item 5 Order field should change to 5,
Item 2 Order field should change to 7,
Item 3 Order field should change to 9 ,
Item 4 Order field should change to 12

**The Recycler View items:**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Answer one**, rebuild/refresh the recyclerview with new data after changing the database.

**Answer two**
Roughly speaking you have to

1. ascertain the range of the affected rows (those whose order is between the from an to)
2. shift the values of the affected rows that are NOT the row being moved using the value from the next row in the direction of the move
3. change the value in the moved row

This is quite complex especially if all of the stages are to be combined. However, this is achievable with SQLite using Common Table Expressions (temporary tables that exist just for the duration of the query).

The following is a demonstration that solves the issue posed i.e. changing from:-

[image]

to

[image]

This is the demo (commented and formatted) that demonstrates the core query that would be implemented in Room (the comments indicate the core query):-

```
/* Just in case the environment has not been cleanup, clean it up*/
DROP TABLE If EXISTS example;
/* Create the table to be demonstrated */
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS example (
    orderinrecyclerview INTEGER, 
    orderfieldvaluesfromtable INTEGER, 
    textfieldvaluesfromtable TEXT
);
/* Add the data for the demo */
INSERT INTO example VALUES
    (0,2,'Item 1'),
    (1,5,'Item 2'),
    (2,7,'Item 3'),
    (3,9,'Item 4'),
    (4,12,'Item 5'),
    (5,16,'Item 6')
;
/* Show the original data as RESULT 1 */
SELECT * FROM example ORDER BY orderfieldvaluesfromtable;

/*<<<<<<<<<< THIS IS THE CORE QUERY BEING DEMONSTRATED >>>>>>>>>>*/
WITH 
    /* CTE (Common Table Expression which is temp table that exists only for the duration of the query) 
        store the from and to values for the move to be made, 
        so values can be obtained whenever needed
    */
    cte_args(fromvalue,tovalue) AS (
        SELECT 
            12 /* will not be hard coded but passed/bound via  arg*/,
            5 /* will not be hard coded but passed/bound via arg */
        ) /* from to values*/,
        
    /* Second CTE to get all the rows that will be affected, along with the new replacement value */
    /* This is done in two stages 
        stage one gets all affected rows EXCEPT the actual row being moved.
        stage two gets the actual row being changed
    */
    cte_rowstochange(rowid,originalorder,neworder) AS (
        SELECT 
            rowid, /* the rowid (always exists for tables unless WITHOUT ROWID table (ROOM does not support WITHOUT ROWID tables)) */
            orderfieldvaluesfromtable,
            (
                SELECT orderfieldvaluesfromtable 
                    FROM example 
                    WHERE orderfieldvaluesfromtable > e.orderfieldvaluesfromtable /* e is the primary query example table as opposed to subquery example table */
                    ORDER BY orderfieldvaluesfromtable ASC /* want the next higher */
                    LIMIT 1 /* only want the 1 value */
            ) /* The value of the order in the next row (next higher order) */
            FROM example AS e /* need to alias the table for WHERE clause above which accesses the same table */
            WHERE orderfieldvaluesfromtable >= (SELECT tovalue FROM cte_args)
            AND orderfieldvaluesfromtable < (SELECT fromvalue FROM cte_args)
            UNION ALL SELECT 
                rowid,
                orderfieldvaluesfromtable,
                (
                    SELECT tovalue FROM cte_args
                )
                FROM example
                WHERE orderfieldvaluesfromtable = (SELECT fromvalue FROM cte_args)
                ORDER BY orderfieldvaluesfromtable ASC
    )
UPDATE example 
    SET orderfieldvaluesfromtable = (
        SELECT neworder 
        FROM cte_rowstochange 
        WHERE example.rowid = cte_rowstochange.rowid
    ) 
    WHERE rowid IN (
        SELECT rowid FROM cte_rowstochange
        )
;
/*<<<<<<<<<< END OF THE CORE QUERY >>>>>>>>>>*/
SELECT * FROM example ORDER BY orderfieldvaluesfromtable;

/* Cleanup testing environment */
DROP TABLE If EXISTS example;
```

To use the above in Room, then you just need the core query (adjusted to table args for the from an to values) e.g. :-

```
Query("WITH cte_args(:fromvalue,:tovalue) AS (SELECT    12,5),cte_rowstochange(rowid,originalorder,neworder) AS (SELECT rowid,orderfieldvaluesfromtable,(SELECT orderfieldvaluesfromtable FROM example WHERE orderfieldvaluesfromtable > e.orderfieldvaluesfromtable ORDER BY orderfieldvaluesfromtable ASC LIMIT 1) FROM example AS e WHERE orderfieldvaluesfromtable >= (SELECT tovalue FROM cte_args) AND orderfieldvaluesfromtable < (SELECT fromvalue FROM cte_args) UNION ALL SELECT rowid,orderfieldvaluesfromtable,(SELECT tovalue FROM cte_args) FROM example WHERE orderfieldvaluesfromtable = (SELECT fromvalue FROM cte_args) ORDER BY orderfieldvaluesfromtable ASC) UPDATE example SET orderfieldvaluesfromtable = (SELECT neworder FROM cte_rowstochange WHERE example.rowid = cte_rowstochange.rowid) WHERE rowid IN (SELECT rowid FROM cte_rowstochange);")
fun moveOrderDown(fromvalue: Int,tovalue: Int)
```

- **NOTE** obviously the component names (tables and columns therein) would have to be changed to suit the actual tables and columns i.e.

  - the tablename **example** would have to be changed to reflect whatever that table is
  - column **orderfieldvaluesfromtable** would have to be changed.
- Other component names can remain as is i.e.

  - **rowid**, **e**, **tovalue**, **fromvalue**, **neworder**, **cte_args** and **cte_rowstochange**
  - all except **rowid** could be changed consistently if required. **rowid** MUST be **rowid** it is the name of a hidden column that exists in all tables that are not WITHOUT ROWID tables or virtual tables (none of which Room supports directly (full text search aka FTS being an exception)).

**Important**
The above just solves moving an order to a lower order. The logic for the move to a higher order would be similar but reversed. You would likely want a `moveOrderUp` function. You could perhaps have a third function that determines which move function to invoke e.g.

```
fun moveOrder(fromvalue: Int, tovalue: Int) {
    if (fromvalue == tovalue) return
    if (fromvalue > tovalue) {
        moveOrderDown(fromvalue,tovalue)
    } else {
        moveOrderUp(fromvalue,tovalue)
    }
}
```

Further more the solution is in-principle and has not been exhaustively tested and may therefore have undetected issues.